# How to make the body textarea of form pre filled in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple form

```
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
  </div>
```

now I want the textarea to be already pre filled with some text (preferably html), how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want a value to be filled in then use this:

```
 <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :title, :input_html => { :value => "This is title field value." } %>
        <%= f.input :body, :input_html  => { :value => "This is body field value." } %>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is too few details in your question. There is an option for `input` method to specify a `value`. But I'd say it is not very good practice.

The good practice would be:

- for existing record show what it has in `body`: it already works
- for a new record, if you want default `body` text, you'd better specify it on creation
  `@rec = Record.new(:body => "default text")`